# React d3.js scaleTo and translateTo doesn't work with .transition

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am working on a react app where I need to center on an x, y, k (zoom), but also want to animate it.

Zoom behavior:

```js
this.zoomBehavior = d3
      .zoom<SVGGElement, undefined>()
      .scaleExtent([0.3, 12])
      .on("zoom", (e) => this.zoomed(e));
```

centering function:

```js
const transition = d3.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .ease(d3.easeCubicOut); 

d3.select<SVGGElement, undefined>(this.svgRef.current!)
      .transition(transition)
      .call(this.zoomBehavior.scaleTo, k)
      .call(this.zoomBehavior.translateTo, x, -y)
```

for some reason, if I exclude `.transition()` from the `d3.select`, then it works but doesn't animate. But if I include it, then it doesn't move the view at all. I have tried also using `.transition()` without any animation customization.

I also loooked at this [resource](https://observablehq.com/@d3/programmatic-zoom) from d3 and tried the random function but it didn't recenter where I wanted.